# Acrobat Reader-how to print only the odd pages?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I want to print on one side and the other of the page. So what I do now is write 1,3,5..., the odd pages pages and later, the even ones. What option is so that is done automatically?
I have version 9.4.6 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expand `More Options` in the Print dialog box.  I'm using Acrobat X but hopefully this will work for your version as well.

[image]

Comment: I upgraded to X

Answer (score 0):

There should be a option to select the pages of a document you want to print, if so then yes just select the ones you want for the first side, print, flip and do again.